# HTTP post in angular

Tags: angularjs, post

I'm pretty new to angular and I'm trying  to do an AJAX post. However I keep getting a bad request message. My code is below

```
   insertStaff: function () {
            var local = "http://localhost/";

            $http({
                url: local + 'xsg/RoomService.svc/rest/InsertChanges',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { "personId": "3", "staffId": "2", "jobId": "waiter", "Year": "2015", "Name": "Smith", "Comment":"Test" }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
        },
```

I suspect my problem lies in the way I'm passing the parameters...in angular can I pass the data in this way...there seems to be conflicting views on the net?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate this request with Postman?

Comment: what request is the server expecting?

Comment: How can u tell the problem is in the angular side, what is the response code received?

Answer (score 0):

i use to send my data like this

```
          data: $.param({
                content: content,
                type: type,
                detail: detail,
                user: user,
                option: options

           }),
```

and it works, try it and let me know if it works for you.